Hydrogen atom orbital calculations using Quantum-Espresso and Octopus
I calculated the orbitals of hydrogen atom using two different approaches: time-dependent density functional theory (TD-DFT) and density functional theory (DFT), and found differences in the resulting patterns.
I used the calculation codes Octopus for TD-DFT and Quantum-Espresso for DFT.
There is an analytical solution for the orbitals of hydrogen atoms, with the s-orbitals being spherical , the p-orbitals being 2-lobes, and d-orbital being 4-lobes.
In the calculation using Octopus, I obtained orbitals close to the analytical solution.
However, in the case of calculation using the Quantum-Espresso, all from the first to tenth orbitals appeared as s-orbitals (spherical).
I'm confused as to why I got these results.
If anyone has had a similar experience, please let me know.

Remember that all orbitals in a subshell are degenerate, and therefore there is no reason why you should get $p_x$, $p_y$ and $p_z$ as actual solutions; any set of three orthonormal linear combinations is a perfectly good solution. There isn't even any external field to define the axes $x$, $y$ and $z$ (in the usual Cartesian quantum mechanics nomenclature), so even if the software did give you a "pure" $p$-state it would not usually be aligned with a particular Cartesian axis choice by the user.
Of course, the software could give you a set of $p_x$, $p_y$, $p_z$ orbitals, but it's incredibly unlikely unless the states were initialised like that; if you initialise your unoccupied Kohn-Sham states with random numbers, then you would expect a roughly spherical set of states to be found. Essentially, the set you get is arbitrary since they are all degenerate; the same is true of $d-$ and $f-$states (and higher).
There will be a very small interatomic interaction because of the periodic images of your atom (since Quantum Espresso is a 3D periodic code), which will lift the degeneracy slightly and give preferred combinations, but this will be an extremely small effect if you've converged your results with respect to the supercell size.
Note that if these orbitals were occupied then it is a different matter: approximate DFT functionals would actively favour a spherical mixture, because of the residual self-interaction, which means that mixtures of states are lower in energy than pure states (in violation of Koopman's Theorem).

I am not able to fully understand the answer
My current interpretation:
(1) Under periodic conditions, orbits in a degenerate state tend to have no specific directionality and instead take a spherically symmetrical shape.
(2) This is due to symmetry due to periodic conditions and the randomness of orbital initialization.
(3) Under non-periodic conditions, the symmetry of the system is broken, and px, py, pz, and d-orbitals close to the analytical solution are easily obtained. Thus, it is a natural consequence that the shape of the orbit changes due to the influence of periodic conditions.

@user11928 no, there is no reason to get px, py and pz solutions from any particular software, periodic boundary conditions are irrelevant. Of course, if your software uses localised orbitals then it may initialise orbitals in pure states, with a particular choice of x, y and z-axes, but this is a free choice.

I've edited my answer to try to clarify these points.

In the analytical solution of the orbitals of the hydrogen atom, p-orbitals have 2-lobes and d-orbitals have 4-lobes. If the periodic boundary conditions are not relevant, are there other factors?
